# Avoid c++ compiler name resolution for exception class aliases

Tags: c++, templates

I have several custom exception classes defined in my codebase. These typically inherit from a base exception type which itself inherits from std::runtime_error. Such exceptions do not normally need to implement specific behaviours, I just want explicit type names for each specific exception.

The class definition normally look like this:

```cpp
class ExceptionA : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
};
class ExceptionB : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
};
```

and the base class looks like this:

```cpp
class Base : std::runtime_error {
public:
    Base(std::string msg)
    : runtime_error(msg)
    {}
};
```

Now, I hate the code repetition to define a simple type with no differences from Base so I want to refactor my code to be DRYer.
My first attempt was via a class template:

```cpp
template<class B>
class Exception : public B
{
public:
    using B::B;
};
```

Then I tried using aliasing:

```cpp
using ExceptionA = Exception<Base>;
```

or

```cpp
typedef Exception<Base> A;
```

but in both cases when I have an uncaught exception the compiler resolved the type name to the template instance:

```sh
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Exception<Base>'
```

How can one actually define a new type via template istantiation? Is there a better solution to this problem that avoids redefining a new type everytime.
I would like to maintain the runtime_error non-trivial constructor with a message string.

The ultimate goal here is to make the code DRYer, I would therefore accept completely different solution from mine if the solution is more elegant.

Comment: `Exception<Base>` *is* the instantiated type,  and attempting to re-instantiate the template with the same argument does not create a new type. `using` and `typedef` only introduce alternative names for types, they don't create new types.

Comment: it is not clear from your question whether you aim for aliases or distinct types. The answer you got gets you the latter, which is better anyhow

Comment: Sorry if the question was not too clear, my main aim is to have the right behavior for the following:
- standard exception catching should be done through the specific exception name and not the template instance used to define it
- consider runtime errors like the one I showed, the error message is unclear

these indirectly point me to the distinct type in my understanding of the language.

Answer (score 4):

You might add tag, something like:

```
template <typename Tag>
class Base : std::runtime_error {
public:
    explicit Base(std::string msg) : runtime_error(msg) {}
};

using ExceptionA = Base<struct TagA>;
using ExceptionB = Base<struct TagB>;
```

Comment: Thanks Jarod, I didn't think of this. This certainly helps, even if it still is IMHO a workaround.